# Swift test if type is collection

Tags: ios, swift

I'm busy trying to write a recursive method. There are no explicit 'children', only collections, so I'd like to checking if I can iterate over some property.

I've seen people find `Swift.Array<String>`, but that will only increase the number of types I need to test for.

Should I try to cast and then obtain a count?

---

```
class ChildArray : NSArray {
}
```

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is not possible in a totally general way in Swift (i.e. pass me anything, Swift or ObjC, and if it's a collection I can recurse though its children, and if any of those are collections, then I can recurse through their children). I just don't think that Swift has sufficient runtime introspection available to make that possible in the most general case. Are you able to restrict your types? For a less general version it may be possible. (Maybe I'm wrong here and someone will have a good answer, but my gut says no.)

Comment: Remember, if the compiler determines that no one ever actually calls subscript or startIndex, it may be allowed to strip that the code, so the methods may not even exist at runtime for a pure Swift type. Or it may inline the methods so even though it really is a collection, there is still no collection method to dispatch to. Swift often avoids dynamic dispatch, and this problem really requires dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of toll-free bridging between Swift and Objective-C. Objects in ObjC have an `isKindOfClass` method to identify if they descend from a class:

```
class ChildArray : NSArray {
}

func isCollectionType(value : AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let object = value as! NSObject

    return object.isKindOfClass(NSArray)
}

var arrayOfInt = [1, 2, 3]
var myArray = ChildArray()
var anInt = 42

println(isCollectionType(arrayOfInt)) // true
println(isCollectionType(myArray))    // true
println(isCollectionType(anInt))      // false
```

Comment: Bridging to Objetive-C is definitely a good idea. But how about checking if the object conforms to the protocol `NSFastEnumeration`?

Answer (score 0):

Checking if an object implements a protocol is usually straightforward.

```
if let _ = myArray as? CollectionType {        
}
```

But this fails with a compiler error.

```
error: protocol 'CollectionType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Using the Objective-C runtime is also out of the question, because this is a pure Swift protocol. You have to use reflection to test this.

```
var myArray :AnyObject = [1,2]

let reflectedArray = Mirror(reflecting: myArray)
if reflectedArray.displayStyle == .Some(.Collection){
    print("is collection")
}
```

Comment: The use of `Mirror` here is interesting, but `displayStyle` isn't fully reliable in this way. There are also `.Dictionary` and `.Set`, which are Collections, but don't return `.Collection`. Worse, if you create a custom `CollectionType`, it won't be a `.Collection` either unless you implement `CustomReflectable`. A struct that implements `CollectionType` will still be `.Struct`.

Comment: I would be happy to find a better way to do this.

Comment: Agreed. It's an interesting problem. But I doubt it's solvable in Swift. I don't know how you would solve it without making a lot of optimizations impossible. (I only mean this in the most general case. If we limit ourselves to certain types, like things that can bridge to ObjC, then it is likely solvable.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty straight-forward way to accomplish the task via parsing object type, if we need `Array`, `Dictionary` or `Set` (list can be updated):

```
func isCollection<T>(_ object: T) -> Bool {
    let collectionsTypes = ["Set", "Array", "Dictionary"]
    let typeString = String(describing: type(of: object))

    for type in collectionsTypes {
        if typeString.contains(type) { return true }
    }
    return false
}
```

Usage:

```
var set : Set! = Set<String>()
var dictionary : [String:String]! = ["key" : "value"]
var array = ["a", "b"]
var int = 3
isCollection(int) // false
isCollection(set) // true
isCollection(array) // true
isCollection(dictionary) // true
```

Hard-code is the drawback but it does the job.